# csv download using simple_html_dom.php creates an extra row

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, export-to-csv

I am using a popular plugin called [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), for exporting HTML to CSV with following code:

```
  <?php

  include "simple_html_dom.php";
  $html = file_get_html('http://siteurl.com');

  header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.csv');

  $fp = fopen("php://output", "w");

  foreach ($html->find('tr') as $element) {
      $td = array();

      foreach ($element->find('th') as $row) {
          $td[] = $row->plaintext;
      }

      fputcsv($fp, $td);
      $td = array();

      foreach ($element->find('td') as $row) {
          $td[] = $row->plaintext;
      }

      fputcsv($fp, $td);
 }

 fclose($fp);

 ?>
```

Everything works fine, except that an empty row is inserted after each row.

What could be the issue?

Attached is the screenshot of my CSV below.

[image: screen shot of my exported csv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have only the first row having header cells... Trying to get data from `<th>` in every row will return nothing, wich explains empty rows you're getting...

You can simply rearrange/change your code accordingly... For example replace your big loop with:

```
$td = array();

foreach ($element->find('tr th') as $th) {
    $td[] = $th->plaintext;
}

fputcsv($fp, $td);


foreach ($element->find('tr td') as $td) {
    $td[] = $td->plaintext;
}

fputcsv($fp, $td);
```

Comment: correct!!.. since $td is an array.. when no th is found.. **fputcsv($fp, $td);** inserts an empty array